# Is minComplete necessary for io_uring network driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, io-uring

Based on my understanding, if we do not use `IOSQE_ASYNC` (meaning new worker threads won't spawned for each entry in submission entry) then the same thread which invokes `io_uring_enter` is expected to handle the entries in the submission Queue.

However, for network applications I am not sure why/when we need to set `minComplete`. Can we not just set it to 0 always and use the head and tail pointers of the completion Queue to determine if there are any entries and then process it. I think there are few use cases when it comes to disk IO but not sure if it is required for network IO.

Especially in case of thread-per-core models where it might be more fitting to set `minComplete` to 0.